# How can I install WSL without Windows Store?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows 10 Enterprise, and I figured it out that this version doesn’t have Windows Store.
How can I install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) with Ubuntu?

Comment: Please see [the Super User version of this question](https://superuser.com/q/1271682/1210833) for the latest information, or to post an answer if you have new info to add.

Answer (score 32):

I found a solution with PowerShell!

**References**

- *[Manual installation steps for older versions of WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual)*
- *[Windows Server Installation Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/windows/wsl/install-on-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN)*

**PowerShell as Administrator**

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

cd c:\

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1604 -OutFile Ubuntu.appx -UseBasicParsing

Rename-Item ./Ubuntu.appx ./Ubuntu.zip
Expand-Archive ./Ubuntu.zip ./Ubuntu

cd ./Ubuntu

.\ubuntu1604.exe

$userenv = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User")
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $userenv + ";C:\Ubuntu", "User")
```

Comment: If I want to use Debian, say, instead of Ubuntu where would I find the replacement for 'wsl-ubuntu-1604' ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/windows/wsl/install-manual#downloading-distributions

Answer (score 8):

I found another way.

You can just run this on PowerShell or Command Prompt as Administrator:

```
wsl --install
```

If you want to see another distribution:

```
wsl --list --online
```

And for installing it, you can run (e.g., install [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) on WSL):

```
wsl --install -d Debian
```

For more information, you can read [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

Comment: The online list works, but the install does not, if you have no store access. See web.-download option in my post below.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell commands [from Bar Nuri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030287/how-to-install-wsl-without-windows-store/59032110#59032110) are perfect, but on my work host for some (corporate?) reason, it doesn't work "as is", due to some permission issue.

#### PowerShell as administrator

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

#### PowerShell using my non-administrator user

```
cd .\debian
.\debian.exe
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
Please create a default UNIX user account. The username does not need to match your Windows username.
For more information visit: https://aka.ms/wslusers
Enter new UNIX username: me
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: password updated successfully
Installation successful!

$userenv = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User")
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $userenv + ";C:\Users\me\debian", "User")
```

Otherwise, when trying to run *debian.exe* as administrator, i'm simply getting a lot of "permission denied" and the install gets locked.

No idea, but it works fine like that --> THANKS!

(And it allows to extract the WSL container in a user-chosen decent place.)

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [the list of provided download links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#downloading-distributions) to import them into WSL.

An alternative is [the hack to get the download link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/generate-direct-download-links-for-microsoft-store-apps) for store apps.

However, both seem to be no longer needed on Windows 11, where WSL has a "`wsl --install --web-download Kali`" option.

I had to update WSL (even after fresh install) to get this option with `--install`: "`wsl --update --web-download`" first. The file version which works is 10.0.22621.2070 (in system32).

Comment: Something seems to be missing at the end.